# Was Charles Xavier's 2nd seizure in Logan consistent?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, logan

Since Charles Xavier's seizures mentally paralyse those within range, that would explain why, in Logan, when he had his 2nd seizure, the car crashed normally however, when Logan killed those men in the hotel that were attacking Xavier and Laura, wouldn't their bodies technically have just fallen to the ground at normal speed when Logan killed them since they were no longer being mentally frozen? They were just lifeless bodies.

Here's the scene:

Comment: Are you sure they don't, I recall that at least one falls to the ground when killed by Logan?  Do you have a clip demonstrating the problem?

Comment: No, you are correct. Rewatching the scene, it is as you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right. That's a logical/continuity issue. Apparently, the character of Charles Xavier, in the comics, had some low-level telekinetic abilities when he was younger that seemed to fade away as he developed his telepathic skills, so, possibly, this could be explained as those latent powers manifesting themselves as the seizures cause all his capabilities to run amok.

But, more likely, IMO, the logic of the sequence was sacrificed for the visuals of "the shot."

> Professor X formerly also possessed low-level telekinetic abilities, though these no longer seem to exist. They appear to be part of his genes however, as Cassandra Nova has telekinetic abilities and is basically a clone of Xavier.
>
> Telekinesis: Telekinetic abilities enabling him to manipulate matter on a low level with the energy of his thoughts.

[X-men Wiki - Character: Charles Xavier](https://xmenrebirth.fandom.com/wiki/Charles_Xavier)